# stacked nodes in directed graph d3js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've a problem with my directed graph in d3js,in a few words:

if number of nodes < 24  the graph is rendered correctly

if number of nodes >= 24 everything was stacked on top left of svg but if I inspect my html code I see all nodes, links and labels...

this is my code:

```
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("x", d3.forceX().strength(8).x(  function(d){ return yScale(d.type) }))
        .force("y", d3.forceY().strength(10).y(height/2))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter().x(width / 2).y(height / 2)) // Attraction to the center of the svg area
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(1)) // Nodes are attracted one each other of value is > 0
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().strength(0.9).radius(50).iterations(10)) // Force that avoids circle overlapping
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(function(d){return d.link_distance}).strength(1))
    var yScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain([1, 2, 3])
    .range([150, width-150])
    .padding(0.6)
    .round(false);
    d3.json("{{=URL('professionista', 'get_current_plan_graph', extension=False)}}", function(error, graph) {
          if (error) throw error;
          var links =  graph.links;
          function getNeighbors(node) {
              return links.reduce(function(neighbors, link) {
                if (link.target.id === node.id) {
                  neighbors.push(link.source.id)
                } else if (link.source.id === node.id) {
                  neighbors.push(link.target.id)
                }
                return neighbors
              }, [node.id])
            }

            function isNeighborLink(node, link) {
              return link.target.id === node.id || link.source.id === node.id
            }
            function getNodeColor(node, neighbors) {
              if (Array.isArray(neighbors) && neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1) {
                if (node.type === 1)
                    return "#3C99FB"
                else if (node.type === 2)
                    return "#9EC2E2"
                else if (node.type === 3)
                    return "#577EA7"
                else
                    return '#dee2e6'
              }

              return '#dee2e6'
            }


            function getLinkColor(node, link) {
              return isNeighborLink(node, link) ? '#000444' : '#E5E5E5'
            }

            function getTextColor(node, neighbors) {
              return Array.isArray(neighbors) && neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1 ? 'green' : 'black'
            }
        
            function selectNode(selectedNode) {
              var neighbors = getNeighbors(selectedNode)
              nodeElement.attr('fill', function(node) {
                return getNodeColor(node, neighbors) 
              })
              labelElement.attr('fill', function(node) {
                return getTextColor(node, neighbors)
              })
              linkElement.attr('stroke', function(link) {
                return getLinkColor(selectedNode, link)
              })
            }
        
          var linkElement = svg.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "links")
                            .selectAll("line")
                            .data(graph.links)
                            .enter().append("line")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                            .attr("stroke", "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2)");

          var nodeElement = svg.append("g")
                              .attr("class", "nodes")
                              .selectAll("circle")
                              .data(graph.nodes)
                              .enter()
                              .append("circle")
                              .attr("r", 30)
                              .attr("fill", getNodeColor)
                              .on('click', selectNode)

          var labelElement = svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "labels")
              .selectAll("text")
              .data(graph.nodes)
              .enter().append("text")
              .text(function(d) {
                return d.codice;
               })
               
          simulation
              .nodes(graph.nodes)
              .on("tick", ticked);

          simulation.force("link")
              .links(graph.links);

          function ticked() {
            linkElement
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            nodeElement
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });
            labelElement
                .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
          }
    });
```

what's wrong with this code?
This happen also if I disable all links and labels, the nodes goes to the corner, please help me!!!

Comment: You could update the question with the content of `graph` for both <24 and >=24 conditions?

Comment: How I can do that? @RobinMackenzie there are a lot of information

Comment: @MicheleSerra is your question still relevant?